# i can't update the angular cli version

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have angular cli 7.1.4 version and I want to update to the latest update but for some reason when I try to update I get a lot of errors.
I tried to use this command ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
is there any fix for this ?
[here is my cmd when I try to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCdui.png)

Comment: Add `--force` flag this will work :)

Comment: If the answer works you may accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can update the global package like this:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

This should upgrade global angular CLI from your current version to the latest version of that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link to be extremely helpful multiple times when updating from what is now a substantially older version of angular: https://update.angular.io/

For your use case I would try the following: https://update.angular.io/?v=7.1-12.0